# PHP Preg Match All but Others Being Returned

Tags: php

I am trying to locate all matching strings in my content with preg_match_all() but it is returning some random results.

Here's my content:

```
This is my content but it is completely dynamic...
[[hello_world]]
[[hello-world]]
[[hello world]]
```

I am wanting to only return this: [[hello_world]]

```
preg_match_all('/[[[a-z0-9_]+?]]/', $content, $matches);
```

but it is returning this:

```
0 => "[[hello_world]]"
1 => "world]]"
2 => "world]]"
```

I am wanting to only return this: [[hello-world]]

```
preg_match_all('/[[[a-z0-9-]+?]]/', $content, $matches);
```

but it is returning this:

```
0 => "world]]"
1 => "[[hello-world]]"
2 => "world]]"
```

I am wanting to only return this: [[hello world]]

```
preg_match_all('/[[[a-z0-9 ]+?]]/', $content, $matches);
```

but it is returning this:

```
0 => "world]]"
1 => "world]]"
2 => "[[hello world]]"
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Huh, why did you copy/paste the question 3 times?

Comment: Because there are three different scenarios.

Comment: i think you need a better regular expression and use preg_match_all

Comment: [`/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/`](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIX3OcUQXLSi6QGqeAl3SQg1DSYw@aEdkZ4@VrEgwize9/EeTPGl1tOl@MLYzuZELhGcgV99mGG9uMBmbw@CQG9pcyzoyOEC45KGGKwQgknpHWI2zzzhqPXGxz@GL/OesTK5u4kDWW8GxIZ3SirZiP2lVVrpjh9g@2lNn56b236dhURman5UrS8)

Comment: @0stone0 this was the solution, thanks! Looks like I just needed the escape \ backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Solution below :

**EDIT** : I modified the regex because it is not limited to the requested characters.

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[(.[a-z0-9-_ ]*)\]\]/s', $input_lines, $output_array);
```